# Fastest way to read .xlsx file with Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I'm trying to read data from a .xlsx file into a MySQL database using Python.

Here's my code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="file", read_only=True)
ws = wb['My Worksheet']

conn = MySQLdb.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SET autocommit = 0")

for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
     sql_row = # data i need
     cursor.execute("INSERT sql_row")

conn.commit()
```

Unfortunately, `openpyxl`'s `ws.iter_rows()` is painfully slow. I've tried similar methods using the `xlrd` and `pandas` modules. Still slow. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you explored `pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', 'sheetname').to_sql(..., conn_details, ..)`?

Comment: EDIT: it seems you cannot use row_offset with ws.rows, only with ws.iter_rows. and I am not sure if ws.rows is any faster

Comment: Saving the sheet as CSV and using `read_csv` decreases the time significantly. `read_excel`  uses Python code while `read_csv`  uses C.

Comment: On another note, doing things row by row is generally slow both in pandas and sql. You may need to process them in batches.

Comment: @JohnGalt, i think you should post it as an answer... ;)

Comment: When you say slow you should provide some context as to the size of the sheet and the time taken.

Comment: Sheet has about 300,000 rows. Takes openpyxl approximately 7 minutes to read.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to benchmark your code and provide information about the size of the worksheet and the time taken to process it.

openpyxl's read-only mode is essentially a memory optimisation which avoids loading the whole worksheet into memory. When it comes to parsing Excel worksheets most of the work involved is converting XML to Python and there are limits to this.

However, two optimisations do spring to mind:

- keep your SQL statement outside the loop
- use `executemany` to pass lots of rows at once to the driver

These can be combined in something like like

```
INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, age…) VALUES (%s, %s, …)"
c.executemany(INSERT_SQL, ws.values)
```

If you only want a subset of the rows then look at using `itertools.islice`

This should be faster than your current code but you shouldn't expect miracles.

When it comes to pure performance, xlrd is a little faster than openpyxl when reading worksheets because it has a smaller memory footprint, largely related to being a read-only library. But it always loads a whole workbook into memory, which might not be want you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rust lib [`calamine`](https://docs.rs/calamine/latest/calamine/) and [python`s bindings](https://pypi.org/project/python-calamine/) for it. It gives 10x-20x speedup on read.

```py
from python_calamine import get_sheet_data

recs: list[list] = get_sheet_data("myfile.xlsx", sheet=0)
```

If you wanna turn it into a `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(recs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the 190K rows data to load of xlsx extension and it didn't take even 10 secs with the calamine engine.

```
pip install python-calamine
```

```
import pandas as pd
from python_calamine.pandas import pandas_monkeypatch

pandas_monkeypatch()
path = "sample_data.xlsx"
x = pd.read_excel(path, engine="calamine")
```

[Check the image to see execution time to read the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gVg6.png)

Answer (score 0):

For reading, try http://github.com/AndyStricker/FastXLSX
It claimed to use expat for event  based parsing and stream based zip reader. Only shared string table has to kept in memory.

If still to slow, you can try compile it with Nuitka. I used to get 25% speed boost with Nuitka compiled lib.

For writing, try http://github.com/kz26/PyExecelerate

For MySQL, try the cython enabled CyMySQL
http://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL
for bulk insertion, in my experience, this noticeably boosted the insertion speed compared to pymysql. The difference I saw only applies to massive bulk insertion in tight loop. Try different  larger batch size to get best speed possible.